# VBA get sql result using column index from CSV Files

Tags: excel, vba

using vba macro   I used the below query and I can able to get the results

`strsQL = "SELECT name,address, balance1,balance2,balance3 FROM userInfo.csv"`

if there any possibility to get the sql results using column index , instead of using column name (address) in VBA macro

Comment: Use `select *` and then in the resulting recordset use the field index, so `rst.fields(1).value` or `rst.fields(1).name` for example?   The complete code of how you are using the SQL may help us to :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.

```
Sub GetMyCSVData()
Dim xlcon As ADODB.Connection
Dim xlrs As ADODB.Recordset

Set xlcon = New ADODB.Connection
Set xlrs = New ADODB.Recordset

Dim currentDataFilePath As String
Dim currentDataFileName As String
Dim nextRow As Integer

currentDataFilePath = "C:\My Data Folder\"
currentDataFileName = "My Data File"

xlcon.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
xlcon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & currentDataFilePath & ";" & "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;"""

xlcon.Open

xlrs.Open "SELECT FirstName, Surname, Age FROM [" & currentDataFileName & ".csv] WHERE SomeNumber > 10", xlcon
xlrs.MoveFirst
nextRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(nextRow, 1).CopyFromRecordset xlrs

xlrs.Close
xlcon.Close

Set xlrs = Nothing
Set xlcon = Nothing
End Sub
```